# How identify rows in big data frame that match rows in little data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with several thousand rows, and a second data frame with a few rows. Both data frames have exactly the same structure (as specified by the R str function), that is, they have the same column names and data types. Data types include character, numeric, and logical.

Is there a clean, elegant way for me to identify (by row number) any rows in the big data frame that match (are identical to) a row in the little data frame?

Comment: Maybe `intersect`? It'd be great if you can provide reprex for us to test :) Use `dput()` to generate such reprex for your large and smaller dataframes.

Comment: Usable example of benson23's suggestion: `df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20); df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,3), b=c(11,13)); intersect(df1, df2)`. Another method is a join, `merge(df1, df2, by=names(df1))`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

```
DF1 <- iris
DF2 <- iris[3:7,]

library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)
DF1[, i := .I] #create index column

DF1[DF2, i, on = names(DF2)] #join on common columns
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Don't know how this answer merited a downvote. (Could add `nomatch=NULL` for the real-world case where maybe not all rows of little are in big),

Comment: @Roland Thanks, Roland. Based on past exposure, there's a non-trivial learning curve getting up to speed with data.table. I will keep your solution in mind, but am hoping for something in vanilla R.

Answer (score 0):

```
shared_rows <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1$rown <- seq_len(nrow(df1))
  unique(merge(df1, df2, sort=FALSE)$rown)
}
```

Comment: Can we elaborate on how this solves the question?

Comment: @Lex Do let me know if you have any specific questions.